# Simple image stitching issue using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently attempting to use OpenCV to build a simple image stitcher capable of stitching multiple images together. I wrote(copied) this simple piece of code as my starting point.

Now, if I choose to stitch foo,doo and roo, It stitches it no problem. But the moment I bring in eoo there is an issue and I get this error.

The problem is that I cannot even seem to find any indication on what this error means? I thaught it might have been a memory issue, but then even if I stitch 3 images containing eoo I still get the issue.

The images that I am using are [4.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsMR7.jpg)[5.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F0aJ.jpg)[6.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxFtj.jpg)[7.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNsgr.jpg)

The error is as follows

```py
[ INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime...
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 1612986244 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp, line 55
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (u != 0) in create, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 436
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 10, in <module>
    result = stitcher.stitch((foo,doo,eoo))
cv2.error: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:436: error: (-215) u != 0 in function create
```

```py
import cv2

stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(False)

foo = cv2.imread("4.jpg")
doo = cv2.imread("5.jpg")
eoo = cv2.imread("6.jpg")
roo = cv2.imread("7.jpg")

result = stitcher.stitch((foo,doo,eoo))

cv2.imshow("camera",result[1])
cv2.waitKey(10000)
```

Comment: You haven't told us any details abotu waht is different about image 6.jpg but you can see in the error message that it is telling you that OpenCV has run out of memory. If you watch the memory usage as you run your application, what happens?

Comment: I will post the images now(once I have discovered whats the convention for posting images here)

Also, I have been running this on my raspberry PI(1 gb Ram) and it never has less than 200mb of ram left. 
When I tested it now om my 8gb Ram pc, It uses maybe 500mb of ram and still have many GB's to spare when the error comes up. 

Could it be that my images are a bit rotated? As I understand this is just for stitching panoramas

Comment: Images are now in the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential change that may help is to use OpenCV's GPU support to improve the performance of the image stitching pipeline with `cv2.createStitcher(True)`. I was unable to replicate your error message as using any combination of images created a successful stitched image.

[image]

```
import cv2

stitcher = cv2.createStitcher(True)

foo = cv2.imread("4.jpg")
doo = cv2.imread("5.jpg")
eoo = cv2.imread("6.jpg")
roo = cv2.imread("7.jpg")

result = stitcher.stitch((foo,doo,eoo,roo))

cv2.imshow("camera",result[1])
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I still get the errors even with the GPU flag set to true. The errors on my Windows machine and Raspberry pi is also different, Intersting, It seems that some system dependant issue is showing its head here. 

Errors on windows PC -->
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 10, in <module>
    result = stitcher.stitch((foo,doo,eoo,roo))
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matri
x.cpp:367: error: (-215:Assertion failed) u != 0 in function 'cv::Mat::create'

Comment: PI->[INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime..
OpenCV Error:Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 24440442 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp, line 55
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (u != 0) in create, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/core/src/umatrix.cpp, line 383
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "new.py", line 10, in <module>
    result = stitcher.stitch((foo,doo,eoo,roo))
cv2.error: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3 3.3.1/modules/core/src/umatrix.cpp:383: error: (-215) u != 0 in function create

Comment: Interesting. Does stitching without 'eoo' on both machines work? Maybe your OpenCV version is outdated. Try updating it with 'pip install --upgrade opencv-python`

Comment: Excellent, I got it to work! Here is what I did. -> I upgraded openCV to version 4. Then the stitcher function becomes "stitcher = cv2.Stitcher.create(True)" 
then I get a working version! Thank you

Comment: I install `opencv-python-4.1.0.25` but when i `import cv2` it uses `OpenCV(3.4.2)`. how to change the version for cv2 ?